# Stripe subscription upgrading and downgrading.

Tags: stripe-payments, subscription

This question is for anyone who's experienced with Stripe. I've run into a situation that may be pretty specific, but I'm hoping I could get some help with. I am creating a system where a user can pick from many different options and set up a yearly subscription based on their selections. So there is no set plan cost, the subscription cost is variable.

Now, if someone creates a subscription for $100.00 dollars, then in a month decides next year they'd like to reduce their subscription to $50.00 they can do so. However, they will not receive a prorated refund due to the downgrade for the current subscription period. My issue is, let's say they change their mind and realize the $100.00 service is worth it. So much so they actually want to change their subscription from $50.00 to $120.00 in the current subscription year. I would like to charge them a prorated fee, but if I do that they will be charged for the difference of $50.00 and $120.00, not $100 (which they paid originally) and $120. Is there anything I can do to allow for such a situation to occur?

Comment: Is the downgrade from the $100 plan to the $50 immediate?

Comment: That was how I was expecting it to work. Downgrade immediately so if they never touch their options again stripe will bill them $50.00 next year.

Comment: If the downgrade is immediate why not just prorate it? So Stripe will calculate the amount they should be refunded and just applies it to to their next bill

Comment: The client would not be happy with that method unfortunately, once a user signs up they do not want to issue a refund whatsoever. A user having the ability to downgrade only allows them to control what they are charged for the next subscription period.

Comment: So they can upgrade at any time but downgrades don't go into affect until the next billing cycle?

Comment: Yeah, and the billing cycle is one year. Essentially they want to stop a user from paying for a high subscription, then reducing their subscription significantly and having most of what they paid refunded. It is a little strange, but one thing they were adamant about.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that in order to make this work I'll have to implement the calculation of a proration amount myself. So in the case a user pays for a $100 subscription, downgrades to $50, and then sometime later in the same year upgrades to $120.

The solution I see is to save the maximum amount they've paid for their subscription in my local database record. When they upgrade, if their new plan cost is greater than the maximum they've paid, I need to set their stripe subscription to the new amount without proration, then calculate the difference between the max they've paid and the new plan amount, prorate the cost and charge them manually using a stripe charge. Kind of a roundabout way to do it but it accomplishes the goal as far as I can see at the moment.